# Using USB to HDMI to extend screen

Tags: usb, video, display, hdmi, lenovo-laptop

So I have a Lenovo Yoga with 1 HDMI port and 2 USB ports (1x3.0 and 1x2.0). I found [this hdmi to usb adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BPEV1XK) on amazon and I'm wondering the following: if I have 3 monitors can I connect 1 via direct hdmi to hdmi and the other 2 via the adapter (assuming I buy 2 adapter, one for each usb port) and have the screen extended. So in other words I would have 4 separate screens.

Note: I want to *EXTEND* the displays not duplicate it. So each of the 4 screens (the laptop screen and then the 3 external monitors) should be able to display different things at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this adapter can work to extend your monitors, you would be better to get a USB3 hub and plug both adapters into this hub. From my experience, the USB2.0 adapters do not have the bandwidth/quality that you would expect from a monitor. While you wouldn't be able to play games on these USB to Monitor adapters, they should be find for office productivity. However, the USB2.0 ones almost give the RDP feel from lag and responsiveness of the mouse and screen dragging.

Comment: ah that is some good information. What does office productivity include? I'm not too worried about games, what about movies played from the HD and other videos streams (youtube, game streams, netflix)?

Comment: I ran multiple of similar (DisplayLink adapters) on USB2.0 ports over the years, I've never seen any lag in day-to-day usage (for 2D stuff anyway).

Comment: @techie007 I think that this goes to show that it can vary based on the adapter. The one that I tried and returned was a USB2.0 $50 adapter from BestBuy.

Comment: @Richard By Office Productivity, I mean email, web browsing, word processing, etc. Basically anything non-3d or moving parts (i.e video/flash).

Comment: @techie007 so would the adapter I linked above from amazon be good enough to stream video without any lag? Btw, I was going to get an amazon 4-port USB 3.0 hub to go along with my purchase.

Comment: @Richard I can't speak to that specific adapter.

Comment: @kobaltz I was using <$50 generic DisplayLink adapters.  I can't recall ever trying full screen video on them or not, but I don't ever remembering thinking anything other than "I'm impressed these things can keep up while using such little CPU". ;)